# What does an orange arrow over a pressens mean?

Tags: remember-me

In *Remember Me*'s Combo Lab, some pressenses have an orange arrow on top of them. Pressens with arrows don't seem to be any different from their arrowless brethren when comparing the effect they have on a combo's damage, regeneration or cooldown reduction. What do these arrows mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it's just the DLC content ;)
Here's the article: http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2013/06/04/remember-me-cheats.htm